# JQUERY replacing negative integer in brackets

Tags: javascript, numbers, integer

I have this string

```
var string = "-200000";
```

and I converted `string` with coma thousands separator with this regex

```
var results = string.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, ",");
```

so it becomes to `-200,000`. The question is how to change the negative sign to brackets, i.e., `(200,000)`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `.replace(/-(.*)/, "($1)");`. Since the replace won't kick in unless there is a match, positive numbers remain as is, while negative numbers replace the - with a ()

```
var results = string.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, ",").replace(/-(.*)/, "($1)");
```